# How to delete leading space from the variable value using sed command

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, sed

Am taking branch name as a input parameter in jenkins, i noticed that input branch name has leading space.

I have already included substution like this to delete the space from the input, but it is not deleting the leading space. It is only deleting the space at the middle or at the end.

`"Branch_name="${Branch_name/ /}"` or
`Branch_name=$(echo "Branch_name" | sed -i -r "s/^\s//g")`

But above methods are not working as intended

Ask is

For eg: Input `<space>Develop_test` this should be store like `Develop_test` without leading space.

Comment: Your `sed` might not recognize `\s`; try `s/^[[:space:]]*//'` (the `/g` is also superfluous if your regex can only match at the beginning of line).

Comment: And also the non needed `-i` switch. Better use the good parameter expansion, like my answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply use multiple substitutions:

```
${Branch_name// /}
#            ^^
```

Ex:

```
$ Branch_name=' foo bar '
$ echo "[${Branch_name// /}]"
[foobar]
```

Or using `tr`:

```
echo "$Branch_name" | tr -d '[[:space:]]'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it is working in my slave but if i use similar case in jenkisn it is not working. am using like below.

Branch_name="${Branch_name// /}"

Comment: Do you use  JenkinsFile ? Can you share it ? Force the use of `bash` to make it works, default Jenkins is `sh`. You can also use `tr ' ' ''`

Comment: Based on question title, seems only leading spaces should be deleted? `Branch_name='    foo  bar '` followed by `echo "[${Branch_name/#+( )}]"` will give `[foo  bar ]`

Comment: @Sundeep OP don't use bash by default, read my comment up to yours